# PHP Function to edit title tags wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Due to an admin error some products title tags on my WordPress/woocommerce site have .co.uk twice - for example 'product name | mysite.co.uk .co.uk'.

I did some research and I figured I need to use a PHP function & filter using `str_replace` to fix this.
This is what I have so far. Where am I going wrong? I think I'm going wrong with getting the title and changing it rather than the string replacement itself.

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'custom_title', 10, 2 );
function custom_title( $title, $post_id ){
    $post_type = get_post_field( 'post_type', $post_id, true );
    if( $post_type == 'product' || $post_type == 'product_variation' ){
        $title = get_the_title( $post_id );
        $title = str_replace(" .co.uk", '', $title);
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of WordPress are you using?

Comment: Wordpress 5.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is likely that `$post_id` isn't properly defined or doesn't get passed to the callback. Also note that `wp_title` is deprecated since WordPress 4.4 and won't work with 5.4.

In any case, WordPress has a [get_post_type()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/) function which should simplify things. Most of the WordPress functions don't require a post ID, they will default to the global `$post` object.

```
add_filter('pre_get_document_title', function($title) {
    $postType = get_post_type();
    if( $postType === 'product' || $postType === 'product_variation') {
        $title = str_replace(' .co.uk', '', get_the_title());
    }
    return $title;
}, 99);
```

---

As you have said below, the post titles have been updated manually with an additional `.co.uk` in the Yoast SEO snippet title.

Assuming you have access to the database, the best way to correct this would be to update the titles, to remove the problem altogether, rather than trying to apply a fix on top of it.

Yoast stores its titles in the `postmeta` table in the WordPress database, under the key `_yoast_wpseo_title`. To replace all the `.co.uk` additions in these titles, you could run a query like:

```
UPDATE `database_name`.`postmeta`
SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, ' .co.uk', '')
WHERE meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_title'
```

Make sure you change the query above so that `database_name` is the correct name of your WP database, and if you have a prefix on your database table names, set the correct table name for `postmeta` as well.

Comment: Still no luck - any way to test this and find out which part isn't working? It's certainly more elegant than my attempt!

Comment: @user2421346 See updated answer. Apparently `wp_title` is deprecated in the newer versions of WordPress. You may also need to decrease the priority of the filter, so it gets applied later in the lifecycle. To check if it's working, change `return $title` to 'test' and see if your page title changes to that.

Comment: Ok - that's working now but strangely that has removed the last bit entirely - it's gone from 'product name | mysite.co.uk .co.uk' to just 'product name'

Comment: @user2421346 Have you changed some settings in WordPress itself, which is controlling how the title displays? Are you using Yoast SEO or anything? Honestly, the best solution to your problem would be to actually correct the errors in the title, rather than relying on a function to hide the problem. I would run a database update to correct the titles permanently.

Comment: Do you think it would be bad practice to just add the ending on with concatenation? Yeah the titles were changed with Yoast - one of the admins edited some of them in bulk and that's what caused it. I was hoping to use a function to avoid fixing it manually

Comment: @Coopero Yes. You're again just patching an issue on top of an issue. Let's start again. How did the titles originally get changed to have .co.uk in them twice? Did the admin manually add the website name in the Yoast title field? Yoast has a snippet variable called 'Site Title' which should be used in the field, and can be updated globally across the whole site from _General Settings > Site Title_. i.e. You shouldn't need to manually add the website name after every title.

Comment: Yeah, when the site started the yoast global setting added the .co.uk to the site title. I think the site title was then changed to include the .co.uk part which caused the duplicates, we then updated our main products manually when we should have used the Yoast global setting. This left all the other ~1600 products with duplicate .co.uk

Comment: @Coopero See updated answer. Best thing to do would be to update the database.